# GPU Particle System

Tags: javascript, three.js

Начал заниматься частичками в tree.js и вобще не могу найти подсказок как работать там с частичками.В исходник частичек я смотрел,но все ровно не пойму как работать с отображением спрайта хотелось бы сделать по другому но пока не знаю как с ними работать кроме простейших настроек может найдется кто то кто изучал данную библиотеку и поможет освоится в ней .

Хотел бы сделать как в унриалке параметр Screen Aligment :SPA Velociti,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но что писать не пойму чтобы повернуть спрайт к камере как надо .Знаю это где то в исходнике написано,но не пойму что там за это отвечает.

Comment: Написать для Вас книгу?

Comment: @OlmerDale нет конешн я такого не прошу просто хотел бы держать связь с человеком с которым бы можно было бы обсудить какие то сложные моменты или заняться общим проектом связанным с этой библиотекой

Comment: Получается что Вы хотите карманного учителя, которому без разницы личные дела, ему ничто не нужно в жизни, кроме как тратить время на Вас? Если бы Вы работали.. делали ремонт, то Вы бы первому встречному пришли бы показывать как делают ремонт от начала и до конца, естественно за свой счет?

Comment: Одно дело когда спрашивают помощь в конкретном вопросе и другое, когда хотят чтобы им одним что-то объясняли по первому требованию.

Comment: @OlmerDale не в коем случаи не так.Просто хотел бы с кем можно было посоветоваться насчет этой библиотеки.Само собой я так же буду отвечать помощью по каким то вопросам,если буду знать ответ .И я добавил то что сейчас меня как раз интересует

Comment: _Хотел бы сделать как в унриалке_ Не путайте игровой движок с фреймворком.

Comment: @prisoner849 Я не путаю я понимаю что ресурсов на вебе намного меньше чем на игровом движке .Но сделать поведение частичек также как я хочу вполне реально,только понять бы что за это отвечает .В крайняк поход мне придется учить его родителя WebGL ,а там наверно и до OpenGL не далеко .... либо WebGL это резанный OpenGL как я понимаю .

Comment: @Gotha Есть [куча примеров](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=Points#webgl_interactive_points) с частицами на официальном сайте Three.js. Разберитесь в них чтобы понять как работать с `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`.

Comment: @prisoner849 это не частички а просто точки которые как я понял строятся на основании меша. Насчет THREE.ShaderMaterial() я не понял что именно там должно отвечать за то что мне нужно. не одного похожего примера на мою задачу я не нашел . Убив очередной день поиска

Comment: Я таки соглашусь с @OlmerDale. Вы хотите, чтобы вас кто-то вел за ручку. Stackoverflow - сайт вопросов о конкретной проблеме (я сделал то-то и то-то, основываясь на таких-то ресурсах, получил вот это вместо ожидаемого, вот код, который у меня есть, как мне дальше быть/что у меня не так, подскажите, люди добрые) для которой можно дать четкий ответ (дружище, у тебя проблема тут и тут, вот в этих строчках). С вопросами типа "хочу, чтобы было вот так, но ничего еще не сделал" - не на этот сайт.

Comment: Частица - точка. Как ее отображать на экране - задача программиста (пресловутый `THREE.ShaderMaterial()` в фрагментном шейдере которого задается отображение точки). То, что показано в вопросе на картинке с примером - можно реализовать тысячью и одним способом, например, использовать массив `THREE.Sprite()` с текстурой, которую можно крутить под определенным углом, можно с помощью массива обычных `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry()`, ориентированных определенным образом.

Comment: @prisoner849 сейчас перечислил и я все понял но вобще я думал что там должен просто какой то параметр отвечать за это который уже вшит в плагин поэтому и нечего не нашел поскольку походу его нету просто а про то что написать самому вобще почему то не приходило в голову =_= на досуге попробую реализовать .